# Dynamically assign Min Max based on grouping of column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, analytics

Working at client site and stuck with a somewhat strange requirement.

Following is the sample input :

```
Category_ID   Tier_No  Tier_Amount
371            1        0
371            2        20
403            1        0
403            2        25
403            3        100
```

Required Output :

```
Cat_ID         Min         Max 
371            0           20
371            20.01       NULL
403            0           25
403            25.01       100
403            100.01      NULL
```

So the logic is as follows :

Dynamically choose how many rows need to be added to the output for 
each Category_ID.
First row's Min would always be zero and last rows's Max would always be NULL.
Each subsequent row(within same category_id) Min Value must be 0.01 more than last rows max value.

Comment: Lead and lag might be useful.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should show us some of your query attempt before asking us for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main starting point is using LEAD analytic function :

```
select t.category_id as "Cat_ID",
   (t.tier_amount+.01)*sign(t.tier_amount) as "Min", 
   lead(t.tier_amount,1,null) over (partition by t.category_id order by t.tier_no) as "Max"
  from mytable t;

Cat_ID  Min     Max
------  ------  ------
 371    0       20
 371    20.01   (null)
 403    0       25
 403    25.01   100
 403    100.01  (null)
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/775ad/11)

Comment: Good answer. I  think it's better(or correct) to use  `over( partition by t.category_id order by t.tier_no)`

Comment: @KaushikNayak exactly, your case seems better Kaushik, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT Category_id,
       CASE WHEN Tier_Amount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE  Tier_Amount+0.01 END  MIN,
       (SELECT MIN(Tier_Amount) FROM T 
            WHERE Category_id = T1.Category_ID 
            AND Tier_No > T1.Tier_No)   MAX

FROM T T1
ORDER BY Category_id,Tier_no
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aff43/5)</kbd>